# Is there a BlackBerry handheld emulator?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I'm looking for a BlackBerry handheld emulator in order to control the BlackBerry handheld device I have using my computer.

Anybody knows if such a software exists?

Comment: Did you mean "Is there a BlackBerry remote access application"?

Comment: Check Impatica viaDock at http://www.impatica.com/products/viadock/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?
http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/13746/?lang=EN